# laravel work safely with mass assignments

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models, laravel-5

I set my laravel models guarded array attribute, now of course I can't set

```
Model::create(['gaurded_field' => 'value']);
```

But how can I insert it safely, only option that comes to mind is to create first, then do:

```
$model_object = Model::create(['other_attributes' => 'other_values']);
$model_object->gaurded_field = 'value';
$model_object->save();
```

but that just requires 2 database queries, 1 insert 1 update, can I set them in 1 query ?

Comment: Please explain why you can't do `Model::create(['field' => 'value']);` after you set `$fillable` on the `Model`?

Comment: @user2094178 if you set fillable/guarded attributes, you can't send them to the create method... because you needed to protect them from being saved from user input in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
$model_object = Model::fill(['other_attributes' => 'other_values']);    
$model_object->guarded_field = 'value'; 
$model_object->save();
```

**EDIT**

There is one more thing. If when using store/update you handle attribute in the code, you can safely add it to fillable attributes (you don't need to use it in guarded.

```
$input = $request->input();
$input['guarded_field'] = 'value';
$model_object = Model::create($input);
```

This way you can safely add this `guarded_field` to fillable fields because in your code you always overwrite it with your value. So no matter what user will send, you will always set your own value. Of course you need to do the same for update (or just unset user value for update if you don't want to make any changes). Sometimes it might be convenient but you need to be very careful with this technique.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did as you suggested in the first part, all good, I would rather not go with second suggestion just because you might forget sometimes.

FYI `Model::fill()`, it's not a static function just create a model instance then use it.